# How to update the A-GPS file on Nikon 5300?

Tags: sdcard, gps, nikon-d5300

I want to update my Nikon 5300's A-GPS file.

At http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/111.html I clicked "Nikon 5300", accepted the license, and pressed "Download", which downloaded a file called `NML_28A.ee`.

Using the D5300 I formatted my SD card (which automatically created a `DCIM` folder on it) then on my computer (Linux) created a `Nikon` folder in that `DCIM` folder and put the file in it:

[image: DCIM/Nikon on Ubuntu Linux]

Then I unmounted safely and inserted the SD card in the Nikon 5300 and pressed:

```
Menu > Setup > Location data > GPS Options > Update A-GPS data > Yes
```

Problem, I get:

```
No A-GPS file found on card.
```

[image: Nikon D5300 No A-GPS file found on card.]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the problem was that you created the `NIKON` folder inside the `DCIM` folder, rather than at the root of SD card's filesystem. From the section **Updating the A-GPS File (D5300)** at the [A-GPS file's download center page](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/111.html) (the same one you linked to):

> Copy the file to the "NIKON" folder on the camera memory card using a computer with a built-in memory card slot or a third-party memory card reader. **The "NIKON" folder should be in the root (top) directory of the memory card**; if a "NIKON" folder does not already exist in this location, create one before proceeding.

Move the `NIKON` folder out of the `DCIM` folder to the root directory, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Format the SD card as FAT (don't use exFAT), create a `NIKON` folder at the root, and copy the `.ee` file into it.